# Fetch Image from server through volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing a project in which I want to fetch image from the server through volley on button click and display in my app.Kindly share the code with me of this scenario. Please help me.

Comment: What you tried  ? Show us some *code*.

Comment: Please provide a real problem you have, with code and explanation about the error. If you need examples use the search on github.com

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-volley-imageloader-networkimageview-example/ check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Cache Mechanism in such way :

```
    /**
     * Image caching used by volley image loader
     * Created by tasneem on 23/7/15.
     */

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

    import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

    public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
            ImageCache {
        public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
            final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
            final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

            return cacheSize;
        }

        public LruBitmapCache() {
            this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
        }

        public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
            super(sizeInKiloBytes);
        }

        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
            return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            put(url, bitmap);
        }
    }
```

And then add into your VolleyControler in such way :

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.zingoy.app.ZingoyApplication;

    /**
     * Class for handling all network requests
     * @author tasneem
     */
    public class VolleyController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = VolleyController.class.getSimpleName();

    private static VolleyController mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private VolleyController() {
        mRequestQueue = mRequestQueue != null ? mRequestQueue : Volley.newRequestQueue(ZingoyApplication.getAppContext());
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new LruBitmapCache());
    }

    public static synchronized VolleyController getInstance() {
        mInstance = mInstance != null ? mInstance : new VolleyController();
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cancelling request");
        return mRequestQueue != null ? mRequestQueue :  Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader != null ? mImageLoader : new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new LruBitmapCache());
    }  
}
```

And whenever you want to render your image you can use :

```
    imageLayout.setImageUrl(url, VolleyController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
```

Comment: private VolleyController() 
{
        mRequestQueue = mRequestQueue != null ? mRequestQueue : Volley.newRequestQueue(ZingoyApplication.getAppContext());
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new LruBitmapCache());
    }

what i write in Volley.mRequestQueue(???)....please help..beacause m new to android

Comment: @AliMehdi,  sorry could n't reply. do you still need help here ?